# How can I make a space available in a razor component to receive an HTML code from the page "index.cshtml"?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working with componentization in razor and I need to componentize an element that I called "field". in my razor component, I need to leave a space so that the user who is going to use my component can pass the HTML code he finds necessary via a .cshtml page. is this possible in razor?

```html
class is-required: true | false
attr for
text label
text description
html HTML

<div class="field is-required">
  <label class="field__label" for=""> Label </label>

  <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
 
  <p class="field__description">Informe os dados solicitados no campo acima</p>
</div>
```

Where is the "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" the parameter for the HTML input would be

Comment: `I need to leave a space so that the user who is going to use my component can pass the HTML code he finds necessary via a .cshtml page. is this possible in razor?`Do you mean you want the user pass code to a input,and then it will be converted to html code in the  .cshtml page?